# Is routes in ruby on rails part of controllers for MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Quick question about the MVC architecture of Ruby on Rails. I'm going through Hartl's tutorial and whenever a new static page is added, one has to update the routes.rb file located in the config folder. Is routes.rb part of Controllers of the MVC architecture? And if yes, why isn't it in the controllers folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the routes is completely seperate from the MVC pattern in theory.  the routes file is specifically for routing your applications TO certain controllers.

You can think of the routes file as a psuedo-controller, which handles the HTTP requests, and which controller to use for that request.

Answer (score 0):

The routes are not a model and not a controller either. Not everything will fit into the MVC design pattern, and there are a [lot of other design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) that can be employed when designing an application.

Routes are a way of mapping the HTTP interface to the controller structure and are roughly a form of the [delegator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

It is a little irregular having `routes.rb` located in `config/` but this convention is unlikely to change. It should probably be in `app/` given the way it's related to that code.